# Add external data and split single row into many rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a table in database which will have 1 row for one ID, as per the requirement I need to add data flags `A,B,C` so now in a temp table I need to have 3 rows for single ID.

Data in database

```
ID   product   
---------------
1    computers 
2    Laptops
3    Speakers
```

Now I want data to be inserted in temp table as

```
ID   product     Flag  //Flag is user defined and will be only 3 any time
----------------------
1    computers   A
1    computers   B
1    computers   C
2    Laptops     A
2    Laptops     B
2    Laptops     C
3    Speakers    A
3    Speakers    B
3    Speakers    C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `VALUES`:

```
SELECT YT.ID,
       YT.Product
       V.C AS Flag
FROM YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES('A'),('B'),('C')) V(C);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have a where clause in table in this case where should I write the cross apply part.

Comment: @Siva It's part of the `FROM`. [FROM (Transact-SQL) - Using APPLY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#using-apply)

Comment: sir your solution worked for SQL Server 2008 but not working for SQL Server 2005, getting error at `Values` will their be any change for v2005, can you please help'

Comment: @Siva 2005 is way out of support. Ideally you should be upgrading that instance.

Comment: thanks for the answer sir, but few of my clients are still using 2005 and are not ready to upgrade, is their any way error can be resolved?

Comment: It's been a long time since I've used 2005, and I don't have access to any instances using it anymore (and for good reason). Perhaps `JOIN (SELECT 'A' AS C UNION ALL SELECT 'B' UNION ALL SELECT 'C') V ON 1=1` will work. Still, I suggest getting those upgrades done, @Siva .

Comment: thanks for the continuous support sir, I have posted the question and was able to get the required output, Client is not ready to upgrade citing the licence cost, so need to deal with it. Thank for your prompt response :)

Comment: @Siva licence cost doesn't mitigate compliance requirements; such as GDPR. :)